# Passing Data in asyncData Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm new to nuxt.js and I want to ask if there is any way to pass data in asyncData.
Here is the code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
    data(){
        return {
          sample: 'asdf',
          baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
        }
    },
    async asyncData ({ params }) {
      let { data } = await axios.get(this.baseUrl)
      return { title: data}
    }
}
</script>
```

I know you don't have access to `this` but is there a way to pass data. Thanks.

Comment: pass data from where?

Comment: in the asyncData, look at `this.baseUrl` in `axios.get(this.baseUrl)` it's invalid. How can I pass it? Thanks.

Comment: you cant pass it from data. You can only use objects from context. Like params, or store. You can put anything in store and access it from asyncDAta

Comment: I see, I know now... so my global data need to pass in the store and it's accessible in the `context.store` or es6 `{ store }`. Thanks..

Comment: well. for global data you use process.env

Comment: Can you give me example about how to use process.env.. I used `global.js` and used `Vue.prototype.$g = ` but the problem is you can't access `this` in asyncData.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this kind of configuration like baseurl defined in env vars in nuxt. [Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/)

```
  // nuxt.config.js
  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
```

Then you can access it anywhere via process.env e.g. in asyncData

```
async asyncData ({ params }) {
  let { data } = await axios.get(process.env.baseUrl)
  return { title: data}
}
```

But for baseUrl for axios you can just define it once e.g. in plugins/axios and then import from there

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.baseUrl
})
```

Or you can use [@nuxt/axios module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module) where u can set baseUrl as an [configuration option](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html)

Comment: You can also access env directly `asyncData({ env })`