# How can I access data in asyncData with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm attempting to build a server-side sortable table with Nuxt, and I'd like to be able to specify the default sort column and direction in my Vue `data`, and access that in my `asyncData` function. Something like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData ({ $axios, params }) {
    const things = await $axios.$get(`/api/things`, {
      params: {
        sort_column: this.sortColumn,
        sort_ascending: this.sortAscending,
      }
    });
    return { things };
  },
  data () {
    return {
      sortColumn: 'created_at',
      sortAscending: true
    }
  },
  // ...
}
</script>
```

But it appears that `data` is not yet available, as `this.sortColumn` and  `this.sortAscending` are not defined. How can I access these defaults when `asyncData` runs while also allowing them to be changed when the user interacts with the page. (Alternatively, what's a better way to structure this?)

Note: This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224224/passing-data-in-asyncdata-nuxt-js), but the accepted answer is not relevant to this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just return it all into asyncData. E.g. something like this:

```
async asyncData ({ $axios, params }) {
    const sortColumn = 'created_at'
    const sortAscending = true
    const things = await $axios.$get(`/api/things`, {
      params: {
        sort_column: sortColumn,
        sort_ascending: this.sortAscending,
      }
    });
    return { things, sortColumn, sortAscending };
  },
```

And it will behave like you want.